# How would I apply two logic cases to a calculation function

Tags: javascript

I have a function which takes in a number and performs a calculation based on a block of the number as follows:

```
if(!isNan(p_Id) && (p_Id.length == 12)){
    if(p_Id.substr(0,5) =="28477") {
    vFlag = true; 
    block = p_Id.substr(4,9); 
   }
else if (p_Id.substr(0,4) == "2373" || p_Id.substr(0,5) == "28477"){
    vFlag = true; 
    block = p_Id.substr(8,7);
   }
}
```

In the case of **28477**, I need to run both of those conditions through the calculation. What would be the best way to apply both block sizes such that the calculation runs and outputs:

**Your Possible Outputs Are:** X and Y.

Comment: Use 2 If statements rather that if & else. Use an array to save the options.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an Else statement use 2 different IF conditions.
Otherwise only one of them would happen (that's the whole meaning of the "else" part).

In order to save both of the options, you would need to use a an array (or 2 different variables, but it's a less modular option).

Please notice that I believe you should have this condition "!isNan(p_Id)" as a deal breaker before continuing for the other conditions.

```
block = [];

if(!isNan(p_Id) && (p_Id.length == 12)){
    if(p_Id.substr(0,5) =="28477") {
    block.push(p_Id.substr(4,9)); 
   }

if (p_Id.substr(0,4) == "2373" || p_Id.substr(0,5) == "28477"){
    block.push(p_Id.substr(8,7));
   }
}
```

Now all you need to do it to iterate the array using a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).